# Supress ngBindHtml error in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ngsanitize

I have a textarea where users can create their own text and are also allowed to use HTML. The text from the textarea is immidiately displayed in a `DIV` as they type.

The `DIV` has the `ng-bind-html` attribute on it. So it tries to parse every single change. Suppose the user wants to type `Hello <strong>world</strong>`.

If the user types ***Hello*** in the textarea then all goes fine. But as soon as they type the first `<` then `ngSanitize` starts to complain about `Error: [$sanitize:badparse] ...`. I find this annoying. I can imagine that in some cases it's handy to be alerted about this. But in my case I don't need the errors.

Is there anyway to supress or disable them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use a filter that calls `$sce.trustAsHtml` to get around any parsing errors.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/95yomb4y/

[**More info on `$sce`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Comment: It is not really the sollution. If user create this content it means that it is not safe ! If you use trustAsHtml you can inject dangerous content.